# Restart forced when set for delay

Tags: windows-10

This has now happened three times:

Windows tells me a restart is needed in order to install an update.
I change the restart time to the day after tomorrow (and set a time as well).
When trying to shutdown, the laptop tells me there are now three options: sleep, update and restart, or update and shutdown. I didn't ask for that, I just told it to delay the restart. There is no 'shutdown' option.
So, not wanting to wait for the update to happen at that moment, I choose 'sleep'.
Next day, I open the laptop, it goes immediately into the update process. You know, the one that I had set for the next day?
Why is that happening? Why is Windows completely ignoring my settings???
How can I change this behaviour?

Laptop is an ASUS K53S.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The system gives you the option to delay the restart to a set time OR the next system shutdown. You can change your prefered time of the restart in case  the time it proposes it to you is inconvenient, but since you weren't using your computer anymore the system had no reason to assume the update would be of any inconvenience to you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Actually, no, it only gave me the option of delaying the restart OR 'restart now'. I remember that this behaviour was different in the beginning: setting a delay really made the system wait for the set time and I could shutdown the system normally in between.